# Validation in plsql for ascii 32 to 126

Tags: plsql

I want my plsql code to accept ASCII values ranging from 32 to 126
I am trying:

`SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN,'[^[:ascii:]],'')`

but this seems to be an issue in Oracle?

Comment: please give more details , like what exactly you are trying to do , what have you tried so far and what issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

You can negate :print: to remove non-printable characters.

```
SELECT c,
       regexp_replace(c,
                      '[^[:print:]]',
                      '')
  FROM (SELECT listagg(chr(LEVEL),
                       '') within GROUP(ORDER BY LEVEL) AS c
          FROM dual
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 256);
```